# How to get related taxonomies based on a category with mysql query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, mysql, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

I have a lot of custom taxonomies for my WordPress site. What I want to do is to **Get Related Custom Taxonomies based on a Category**.

Sample Structure: (Material, OS and Features are Custom Taxonomies.)

| Post | Category | (CT)Material | (CT)OS | (CT)Features |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | A |  | iOS | OLED |
| P2 | B | Metal |  | GPS |
| P3 | C | Glass | Anroid | GPS |

So what I want:

- For Category A: its related taxonomies is **OS** and **Features**.
- For Category B: its related taxonomies is **Material** and **Features**.
- For Category C: its related taxonomies is **OS**, **Material** and **Features**.

I'm not very familiar with complex mysql query, Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Updated: 2022-04-01

I've been able to achieve it by modifying another SQL I got here earlier. My English is not very good, maybe these codes can help everyone to understand my needs. My concern at the moment is whether there is a more efficient and performant way to do this.

```
function get_related_taxonomies($base_term_id, $base_taxonomy, $post_type = 'post') {
    global $wpdb;

    $key = $base_taxonomy . ':' . $base_term_id;

    if ($taxonomies = wp_cache_get($key, 'related_taxonomies')) {
        return $taxonomies;
    }

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT related_tax.taxonomy
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms related
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy related_tax ON (related_tax.term_id = related.term_id)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships related_rel ON (related_tax.term_taxonomy_id = related_rel.term_taxonomy_id)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts posts ON (related_rel.object_id = posts.ID)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships base_rel ON (posts.ID = base_rel.object_id)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy base_tax ON (base_rel.term_taxonomy_id = base_tax.term_taxonomy_id)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms base ON (base.term_id = base_tax.term_id)
    WHERE
        base_tax.taxonomy = '%s'
        AND posts.post_type = '%s'
        AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND base.term_id = %d
    GROUP BY related_tax.taxonomy",
        $base_taxonomy,
        $post_type,
        $base_term_id
    ));

    $taxonomies = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result->taxonomy !== $base_taxonomy) {
            $taxonomies[] = get_taxonomy($result->taxonomy);
        }
    }

    wp_cache_set($key, $taxonomies, 'related_taxonomies');

    return $taxonomies;
}
```

Comment: How this relationships are established? You can use term meta data for this.

Comment: No, it's a multiple custom taxonomies issue, the term meta doesn't meet my need.

Comment: Category A, Category B, Category C : Are those terms or custom taxonomy labels?

Comment: they are `category` terms. let's say there are 100 products under `category` A, what I want to get is `all possible other custom taxonomies` used in these products. note: it's `related taxonomies` instead of `related terms`.